# Does the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}(-),X)$ preserve filtered colimits?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

[image]

I want to apply this Lemma to the functor $X(-)$ for a scheme $X$ which is locally finite presentation over $A$, which by definition is just the functor $\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}\,(-),X)$. But this requires the functor to preserve filtered colimits.

Comment: Where is this lemma from? Also, so you know, [pictures of text are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) - it would be better if you could transcribe the image.